# Can anyone provide step by step process to implement SAML

Tags: saml-2.0

I have a situation where I currently call web focus reports from our JAVA web applications. But is not a secured way calling and I wanted to implement SAML authentication and pass parameters through SAML. Any help in this regard will be great help

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need SAML?

OpenID Connect is a much easier option.

For SAML, you need to implement a SAML stack.

There is more information [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Comment: I need SAML to provide more security to WEBFOCUS calls from JAVA. I want to achieve this through passing SAML tokens instead of POST parameters which are exposed to USER.